# Поиск по дапазону дат

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, prisma

Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию отпусков по диапазону дат, но не знаю как это сделать. Пожалуйста помогите.

База данных postgresql
Backend: nestjs + prisma orm (4.0.0)
Frontend: React

Данные о отпусках хранятся в базе в таком виде:

```
id: Int
userId: Int
dateStart: DateTime
dateEnd: DateTime
```

В фильтре на frontend у меня есть поля:

```typescript
{
    dateStart: Date;
    dateEnd: Date;
}
```

Я не понимаю как сделать запрос в базу так, что-бы вывести результат сопракосновений двух диапазонов.

Следующий запрос отрабатывает неверно:

```typescript
where: {
    dateStart: { gte: dto.dateStart },
    dateEnd: { lte: dto.dateEnd }
}
```

Если я например пользователь в отпуске с 25 января по 2 февраля, а в фильтре укажу сортировку с 1 по 31 января, то отпуск не покажется. В этом примере он не сработает из-за несоответствия условиям dateEnd.

Единственное до чего я смог догадаться, это входные dateStart и dateEnd превратить в массив дат, а затем пройтись по циклу внутри where запроса. Это работает, но медленно. Например если фильтровать целый год, то запрос в базу получается уж большой жирный Пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: Вам нужно добавить условия для каждого значения из фильтра. Как пример: первое значение из фильтра попадает в диапазон отпуска, `OR` второе значение попадает в диапазон отпуска.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Если речь идет о такой конструкции, то она не пройдет:
`OR: [
  { dateStart: { gte: dto?.dateStart }, dateEnd: { lte: dto?.dateStart } },
  { dateStart: { gte: dto?.dateEnd }, dateEnd: { lte: dto?.dateEnd } },
],`

В таком случае если указать диапазон фильтра весь год, то в него не попадет не один из отпусков.

Comment: вам хорошо подойдёт такой запрос: `tstzrange(dateStart, dateEnd, '[)') && tstzrange('[' || $1 || ', ' || $2 || ')')`. тут про tstzrange https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html, тут про операции https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE

Comment: Диапазоны пересекаются, если dateStart отпуска <= dateEnd фильтра и dateStart фильтра <= dateEnd отпуска

Comment: @Dmitriy тогда сделайте наоборот, поиск всех отпусков, у которого дата начала отпуска попадает в даты фильтра `OR` дата конца попадает в даты фильтра.  Так подойдет `OR: [   { dateStart: { lte: dto?.dateEnd, gte : dto?.dateStart } }, { dateEnd: { lte: dto?.dateEnd, gte : dto?.dateStart } }, ]` ?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, Вы мне сильно помогли. Проблема решена. Если можете, оформите этот как ответ. Я проголосую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска по диапазону дат отпусков из фильтра, нужно проверить два условия через или: дата начала отпуска попадает в даты фильтра `OR` дата конца попадает в даты фильтра. В коде это должно выглядеть так:

```
where: {
    OR: [
        { dateStart: { lte: dto?.dateEnd, gte: dto?.dateStart } },
        { dateEnd: { lte: dto?.dateEnd, gte: dto?.dateStart } }
    ]
}
```